# decipher the regular expression

Tags: regex, awk

please help me decipher the regular expression-

```
'!_[$0]++'
```

It is being used to get a MSISDN (one at a time from a file containing list of MSISDN starting with zero )by the following usage:

```
awk '!_[$0]++' file.txt
```

Comment: That's not a regular expression, regexps are inside `/.../`. It's just an ordinary expression containing an array and operators.

Comment: For the record, if it actually were a regular expression, it would nominally contain a syntax error because you cannot have two `+` quanitifers in Awk regex.  Ignoring that -- like for example `mawk` and `nawk` actually do! -- it would match any line containing the literal characters `!_` followed by one or more occurrences of the literal characters `$` or `0` in any mix (i.e. it could be `$$$$` or `0000` or `$` or `0` or `$00$$$0$` etc).  The Awk script for that would be `awk '/!_[$0]+/' file.txt` -- notice the slashes around the expression to make it a regular expression test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a regular expression, it's an arithmetic and boolean expression.

- `$0` = The current input line
- `_[$0]` = An associative array element whose key is the input line
- `_[$0]++` = increment that array element each time we encounter a repeat of the line, but evaluates to the original value
- `!_[$0]++` = boolean inverse, so it returns true if the value was originally 0 or the empty string, false otherwise

So this expression is true the first time a line is encountered, false every other time. Since there's no action block after the expression, the default is to print the line if the expression is true, skip it when false.

So this prints the input file with duplicates omitted.

Answer (score 1):

```
'true'- then the line will be printed

'_[$0]++'- associative array will be incremented everytime when $0 is present.means it will set the number of times each line is repeated.

'!_[$0]++'-this will be true when a line is inserted in the associative array for the firsttime only and the rest of the times it will resolve to false ultimately not printing the line.
```

So all the duplicate lines will not be prited.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a regular expression.  This particular command prints unique lines the first time they are found.

`_` is being used as an array here and `$0` refers to the entire line.  Given that the default numeric value for array element is `0` (it's technically an empty string, but in numeric contexts its treated as 0), the first time you see a line, you print the line (since `_[$0]` is falsy, `!_[$0]` will be true).  The command increments every time it sees a line (after printing -- awk's default command is to print), so the next time you see the line `_[$0]` will be `1` and the line will not be printed